# PHP set_time_limit limit

Tags: php, cron, sleep

**QUESTION**

Would it work fine if I use `sleep(300);` to do a whole day (24 hours) in 5-minute gaps?

This means, **would `set_time_limit (86400);` work?**

*Then I can set my host's schedule to only be used once every 24 hours.*

---

**INFO**

I found what I am doing now on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571125/running-a-php-script-every-5-minutes-and-avoiding-race-conditions) and am now using it to do something every 5 minutes. It works well and is on time with even the seconds correct. (Talking about the gap between each `sleep`) - it sleeps 3 times and then gets called again from my host's-schedular.

I have a scheduled task set up at my host for every 15 minutes, problem is this is not happening every (precise) 15 minutes, but more like 16 and a bit minutes - and after a few hours it is totally out of sync.

If it's possible to use it to not quit within 24hrs, then I can adjust the sleep in the code to make it execute exactly every 5 mins.

---

**UPDATE**

```
17:17:50 22-09-2011 Check done!
17:34:09 22-09-2011 Check done!
17:47:47 22-09-2011 Check done!
```

I ran a script that appended to a file the date and "Check done!" - this was without a loop and `sleep` and that is what I got.

Comment: Show your cron tab entry. Cron should never fall out of sync.

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble fully understanding your question, but it looks like you might want to consider `time_sleep_until`:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php

Comment: @Ben Lee, thats a clever idea! about the cron, not sure if it is cron. I use Netfirms - they call it "Scheduled jobs" not cron... I don't have direct access to actual cron files/stuff.

Comment: just looked it up. Netfirms scheduled jobs are real crons.

Comment: Ok cool, but I still cant access it directly - only through their scheduled jobs page. I think I am going to set it on "daily at 1 AM" then run it for 24 hours before it gets recalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `set_time_limit(0);`, the code will never time out and run forever unless it exits first. For instance I write programs in PHP in a `while(1) { ... }` loop. It ran for about two weeks straight (then I had to restart my computer for some unrelated reason).

Cron is usually accurate though. If your host's cron is so out of sync, you should contact them and ask about it - that's not normal.

EDIT: Also, you might want to consider running it forever and start it manually, then having a cron task that checks if it's still running, and restart it if it isn't.

Comment: Clever EDIT, think you solved my problem. Thanks. Also going to use Ben Lee's `time_sleep_until`

Comment: how would I stop it? Or reset it?

Comment: Well, you could, at the start of the loop, test for a switch. Maybe `if(file_exists("STOP_PROGRAM")) exit;`

Answer (score 2):

> would set_time_limit (86400); work?

Yes.

But don't do that if you run your script through a web server, this would occupy a connection during this whole time.

Comment: I'm debating doing pretty much this. I have a powerful webhost and I know that only one or two connections per week will be calling the script that would be running for an hour. How serious an issue is this? But mine would be `set_time_limit(3600);`