# running a single process in the bakground at all times

Tags: php

How can I run process in the background at all times?

I want to create a process that manages some work queues based on the info from a database.

I'm currently doing it using a cron job, where I run the cron job every minute, and have 30 calls with a sleep(2) interval. While this is working OK, I've noticed from time to time that there is a race condition.

Is it possible to just run the same process all the time? I would still have the cron job attempt to start periodically, but it would just shut down if it sees itself running.

Or is this a bad idea? any possibility of a memory leak or other issues occurring?

Comment: This isn't really a PHP question. PHP is a "compile-on-request" language, where it is compiled and ran by the server only when a url is requested. Without further information on your system (Linux? Windows? Mac?), what you're trying to change (SQL databases? Plaintext files? The fate of the world?), we can't answer anything besides saying that no, PHP is likely not the answer, and you should look for something else usable on your system.

Comment: What is the race condition happening between?

Comment: Other than what @UnstableEagle just stated, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3571146/2518525) might be a good read for you to try prevent that race condition.

Comment: On Unix you can run a process all the time using `/etc/inittab` to start it up. We run lots of PHP scripts in the background like this.

Comment: There's nothing PHP-specific about the question. You can run a PHP script all the time the same way you would run any other script all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some years ago I didn't know about MQ systems and nodejs and etc. 
so then I used code like this and added to cron to run every minute:

```
<?php 

// defining path to lock file. example: /home/user1/bin/cronjob1.lock
define('LOCK_FILE', __DIR__."/".basename(__FILE__).'.lock');

// function to check if process is running or not
function isLocked() 
{ 
    // lock file exists, but let's check if it's running?
    if(is_file(LOCK_FILE)) 
    { 
        $pid = trim(file_get_contents(LOCK_FILE)); // reading process id from .lock file
        $pids = explode("\n", trim(`ps -e | awk '{print $1}'`)); // running process ids
        if(in_array($pid, $pids))  // $pid exists in process ids
            return true; // it's ok, process running
    } 

    // making .lock file with new process id in it
    file_put_contents(LOCK_FILE, getmypid()."\n" );  
    return false; // previous process was not running
} 

// if previous process locked to run same script
if(isLocked()) die("Already running.\n"); // locked, exiting


// from this point we run our new process
set_time_limit(0);
while(true) {
    // some ops
    sleep(1);
} 

// cleanup before finishing
unlink(LOCK_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something called [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) which requires [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/).

Once you have node installed,

Install forever with:

```
 $ [sudo] npm install forever -g
```

To run a script forever:

```
forever start app.js
```